# How to concatenate more than two integer arrays in Java if I don't know the future size?

Tags: java, arrays

I'm doing a homework on Java where I have to transformate a String into an char array and then on an integer array, after that, each position of the integer array must be transformed in binary, so as binary is longer than the same number on decimal, I have to know how length will have my future integer array with the binary numbers to do all the examples that I saw on Internet, if you have another solution please you would help me very much

For example

```
int[] a={1,1,0};
int[] b={1,1,0,0};
int[] c={1,0,1,0,1};
int[] result={1,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1}; // a+b+c
```

Comment: You can [edit] your question instead of posting new information in comments.

Comment: length of a plus length of b plus length of c - Am I missing something?

Comment: How do you not know the size of the final array? It's `a.length` + `b.length` + `c.length`.

Comment: but after that 3 arrays I have to add more arrays and I don't know de size of the final array. That 3 was just an example, but could be n-arrays

Comment: Do you get all the `n` arrays at the start? If so, just follow the provided comments and answers.

Answer (score 1):

For your particular example, you can just sum the lengths of `a`, `b`, and `c` to get the final array size and use `System.arraycopy` to merge them. Demo: https://ideone.com/D2EW2Q

```
int[] a = { 1, 1, 0 };
int[] b = { 1, 1, 0, 0 };
int[] c = { 1, 0, 1, 0, 1 };
final int[] result = new int[a.length + b.length + c.length];
System.arraycopy(a, 0, result, 0, a.length);
System.arraycopy(b, 0, result, a.length, b.length);
System.arraycopy(c, 0, result, a.length + b.length, c.length);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));
```

For a more general approach, you can use Streams. Demo: https://ideone.com/fZhgls

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {
    int[] a = { 1, 1, 0 };
    int[] b = { 1, 1, 0, 0 };
    int[] c = { 1, 0, 1, 0, 1 };
    final int[] merged = merge(a, b, c);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(merged));
}

public static int[] merge(final int[]... arrs) {
    return Arrays.stream(arrs).flatMapToInt(IntStream::of).toArray();
}
```

Comment: I will test it on my code now, however I believe that the general approach could work for me, because I will not know how many arrays I will have to concatenate, therefore I thing on a solution where I can add arrays to a final array one by one

Comment: Does it work for you?